# Zsh: why can't I write an anonymous function alias with double quotations?

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh, alias

I recently created a handy zsh alias to [make a directory and cd into it with a one-liner](https://chris-perry.medium.com/zsh-make-directory-and-cd-into-it-with-one-liner-b03902ffa001):

```
# this works yay
alias vk='() { md $1 && echo $_ }'
```

If I change the alias definition to use double-quotes, it no longer works:

```
# y u no work >:O
alias vk="() { md $1 && echo $_ }"
```

Cool, I used the single quotes and have a working alias but I have no idea why it's fine with one and not the other, especially since double quotes are A-OK with all the rest of my aliases.

Can someone help me understand what's going on under the hood?

Comment: Variable expansion happens in double quotes, not in single quotes. -- Why not just use a normal function for this instead of an alias? `vk() { md "$1" && echo "$_"; }`

Comment: I could, that would work too. My general rule is to limit functions to multi-line code blocks to keep the global scope as lean as possible. But in any case thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I'm not sure, from a practical standpoint, what benefit keeping the global scope lean has. Technically, functions aren't scoped anyway, at least not in the same sense as variables.

Comment: @ChrisPerry : Bear in mind that functions also work inside zsh scripts, while an alias does not, unless this is explicitly enabled. Using an alias with a fake function just to avoid writing a real function seems to me a somewhat odd approach.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and feedback. I've revised my medium article (link in the original post) to now recommend using a function over an alias for this method.